# Python Pandas dataframes contains wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have some functions that trough an API download data and store it inside dataframes. The problem is that when I do multiple requests the dataframes completely report wrong values.
Here are some examples, first I do a single request:

```py
start_date = "10/01/2023"
end_date = "10/12/2023"
timeframe = '1hour'

df_usdjpy = DownloadData('USD/JPY',start_date,end_date,timeframe)
print(df_usdjpy.getData())
```

Result:

```
                     Timestamp     Open     High      Low    Close
0    2023-01-10 00:00:00+00:00  131.731  132.221  131.670  131.700
1    2023-01-10 01:00:00+00:00  131.700  131.736  131.380  131.518
2    2023-01-10 02:00:00+00:00  131.518  131.895  131.485  131.788
3    2023-01-10 03:00:00+00:00  131.788  131.917  131.777  131.830
4    2023-01-10 04:00:00+00:00  131.828  132.016  131.813  131.984
...                        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
5729 2023-12-08 17:00:00+00:00  144.877  144.976  144.740  144.805
5730 2023-12-08 18:00:00+00:00  144.805  144.962  144.761  144.934
5731 2023-12-08 19:00:00+00:00  144.933  144.967  144.829  144.964
5732 2023-12-08 20:00:00+00:00  144.965  144.995  144.933  144.987
5733 2023-12-08 21:00:00+00:00  144.987  144.998  144.902  144.902
```

The problem rise when I do multiple dataframes, here's an example:

```py
start_date = "10/01/2023"
end_date = "10/12/2023"
timeframe = '1hour'

df_gbpusd = DownloadData('GBP/USD',start_date,end_date,timeframe)
df_usdjpy = DownloadData('USD/JPY',start_date,end_date,timeframe)

print('GBP/USD \n ------')
print(df_gbpusd.getData())
print('USD/JPY \n ------')
print(df_usdjpy.getData())
```

Result:

```
GBP/USD 
 ------
                     Timestamp     Open     High      Low    Close
0    2023-01-10 00:00:00+00:00  1.21833  1.21978  1.21638  1.21738
1    2023-01-10 01:00:00+00:00  1.21737  1.21845  1.21653  1.21796
2    2023-01-10 02:00:00+00:00  1.21796  1.21859  1.21566  1.21685
3    2023-01-10 03:00:00+00:00  1.21686  1.21756  1.21584  1.21675
4    2023-01-10 04:00:00+00:00  1.21678  1.21715  1.21581  1.21595
...                        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
5729 2023-12-08 17:00:00+00:00  1.25368  1.25464  1.25227  1.25452
5730 2023-12-08 18:00:00+00:00  1.25452  1.25554  1.25429  1.25508
5731 2023-12-08 19:00:00+00:00  1.25510  1.25552  1.25486  1.25498
5732 2023-12-08 20:00:00+00:00  1.25498  1.25501  1.25427  1.25475
5733 2023-12-08 21:00:00+00:00  1.25476  1.25490  1.25440  1.25445

[5734 rows x 5 columns]
USD/JPY 
 ------
                     Timestamp       Open       High        Low      Close
0    2023-01-10 00:00:00+00:00  131.73100  132.22100  131.67000  131.70000
1    2023-01-10 01:00:00+00:00  131.70000  131.73600  131.38000  131.51800
2    2023-01-10 02:00:00+00:00  131.51800  131.89500  131.48500  131.78800
3    2023-01-10 03:00:00+00:00  131.78800  131.91700  131.77700  131.83000
4    2023-01-10 04:00:00+00:00  131.82800  132.01600  131.81300  131.98400
...                        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
5729 2023-12-08 17:00:00+00:00    1.25368    1.25464    1.25227    1.25452
5730 2023-12-08 18:00:00+00:00    1.25452    1.25554    1.25429    1.25508
5731 2023-12-08 19:00:00+00:00    1.25510    1.25552    1.25486    1.25498
5732 2023-12-08 20:00:00+00:00    1.25498    1.25501    1.25427    1.25475
5733 2023-12-08 21:00:00+00:00    1.25476    1.25490    1.25440    1.25445

[5734 rows x 5 columns]
```

As you see, the end result is a mess. I can run multiple times and I'll get always different outputs. I did several tests with tons of data and the problem never emerge until I create multiple dataframes, hence I exclude the problem is on my class or the API I'm using.

Someone has some clues?

#### Edit: Including DownloadData class

This is the complete code of the class DownloadData. If something is not clear about it please ask.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import os 

class DownloadData():
    def __init__(self, ticker, start_date, end_date,timeframe):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        ticker : int
            Dukascopy ticker of desired instrument
        start_date : str
            Start date in a string like "DD/MM/YYYY"
        end_date : str
            End date in a string like "DD/MM/YYYY"
        """
        self.api_key = '-------' # Hidden 
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.timeframe = timeframe

    def getData(self):
        # Link for doing an API request
        url = 'https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=api/historicalPrices' 
        
        # Date must be converted to UNIX with milliseconds
        start_date = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(self.start_date, "%d/%m/%Y").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)) * 1000,
        end_date = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(self.end_date, "%d/%m/%Y").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)) * 1000
       
        # Initialising an empty dataframe that will be filled with data
        data = pd.DataFrame()

        download_progress = None

        # I had to create a while loop because the API let me download max. only 5000 rows of data at once. 
        # So I create a loop that will do multiple requests, basically it donwload 5k rows of data at time 
        # until all data relative to the desired datetime range has been donwloaded.
        while(True):
            # If I want data from 01/01/2023 to today, then I'll be given only the most recent 5k rows of data. 
            # Then I check if I already downloaded data into the dataframe, if yes less_recent_value assumes 
            # the value of the first row Timestamp, so that this cycle will download the 5k rows of data that 
            # precedes the ones already downlaoded. 
            if not data.empty:
                less_recent_value = min(data['Timestamp'].iloc[0],end_date)
            else:
                less_recent_value = end_date

            params = {
                'key': self.api_key,
                'instrument': self.getTicker(),
                'timeFrame': self.timeframe,
                'count' : 5000, # Max rows of data downloadable, can't insert a value higher than this. 
                'start' : start_date,
                'end' : less_recent_value,
            }

            response = requests.get(url, params=params)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                new_data = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
                
                # Just converting a json file into a dataframe
                if params['timeFrame'] == 'tick':
                    new_data_clean = pd.DataFrame(new_data['ticks'].apply(lambda x: {'Timestamp': x['timestamp'],'Bid': x['bid'], 'Ask': x['ask']}).tolist())
                else:
                    new_data_clean = pd.DataFrame(new_data['candles'].apply(lambda x: {'Timestamp': x['timestamp'],'Open': x['bid_open'], 'High': x['bid_high'], 'Low': x['bid_low'], 'Close': x['bid_close']}).tolist())
                
                # Attaching new data to the main dataframe
                data = pd.concat([new_data_clean, data], ignore_index=True) # Maybe ignore_index=True is the problem?
                # Saving the less recent datetime of my data, so I can use it in the next call in order
                # to download all data previous that date. 
                current_progress = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['Timestamp'].iloc[0] / 1000) 
            else:
                print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
            
            # Check if all desired data has been downloaded or if another API call must be done
            if not download_progress == current_progress:
                download_progress = current_progress
                #print('Downloading... ',download_progress)
            else: 
                break
                              
        # Check if there are duplicated rows
        duplicated_rows = data[data.duplicated()]
        if not duplicated_rows.empty:
            print("There are duplicated rows in the combined DataFrame.")
            print(duplicated_rows)
        else:
            print("No duplicated rows found.")

        # Convert UNIX timestamp to human readable date
        data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'], unit='ms',utc=True)
        return data 

    def getTicker(self):
        '''
        This method takes a string and find the correct ticker of the broker.
        E.g. self.ticker = GBP/USD -> getTicker -> 2026, because the API uses that number in order to identify GBP/USD. 
        '''
        # API endpoint URL
        url = 'https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=api/instrumentList'

        # Add the API key as a query parameter
        params = {
            'key': self.api_key,
        }

        # Send a GET request with query parameters
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)

        # Process the response
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
        else:
            print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")

        filtered_data = data[data['name'] == self.ticker]

        if not filtered_data.empty:
            found_id = filtered_data['id'].values[0]
            #print(f"ID for {self.ticker}: {found_id}")
            return found_id
        else:
            print(f"No data found for name: {self.ticker}")
```

Comment: Without knowing what `DownloadData(...)` is doing, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong here. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: While you're editing, please provide the code for `getData()`

Comment: @Nick Updated as requested.

Comment: @Squarish updated as requested

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: I presume you don't get any error messages from running the code? And that the place where the data starts being wrong is at line 5000? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Without access to the data source it's hard to do any more testing.

Comment: @Nick as you see from example, data start to being wrong at random places... Basically from the DownloadData object it gets weird and the dataframe becomes a mixture of previous dataframes values. If I run only one insntance of DownloadData no error occours... Which led me to believe it's a problem of Pandas...

Comment: Ok, apparently the problem is with the API. If I use time.sleep(15), yes at least 15..., between each call the problem seem solved